# Derivative of $\arcsin(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ .

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

My intuition says that since $\sin(x)$ and $\arcsin(x)$ are inverse of each other, their derivatives must be reciprocal. I have previously proved the fact that $\arcsin(x)'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ but it doesn't match my thought about being reciprocal and also observation.

Here is the illustration showing the slope is probably reciprocal of each other: [image]

The question is why is the idea wrong in this case i.e $\arcsin(x)\neq\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$?

Comment: If you have $y = \arcsin x$ then $$(\arcsin x)' = \frac{1}{\cos y}$$ You have your variables mixed up because you are only plotting things in terms of "$x$", but these $x$ mean different things.

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac1{dx/dy}$ is correct, but you need to remember that $\frac{dx}{dy}$ has $y$ as its variable

Comment: @WilliamJohn. $\arcsin(x)$ is neither equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ nor to $\frac{1}{\cos x}$. Please edit your question.

Comment: Apologies to all after realizing comment and thinking a bit  I feel so dumb to ask this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  $ y = \arcsin(x) $

Then,

$ x = \sin(y) $

Using implicit differentiation,

$ 1 = \cos(y) y' $

Hence,

$ y' = \dfrac{1}{\cos(y)} $

But $\cos(y) = \sqrt{1 - \sin(y)^2} = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$

Therefore,

$y' = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} $

Answer (score 2):

They are reciprocal in the sense that, if the derivative of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$, then at the $y$ where $\arcsin y = x$, the derivative of $\arcsin y$ (w.r.t $y$) is $\frac1{\cos x}$.

Then to represent that derivative using $y$, one has to simplify $\frac{1}{\cos (\arcsin y)}$.

In fact, $\arcsin y = x$ means $y = \sin x$, so

$$\frac{d}{dy}\arcsin y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}} = \frac{1}{|\cos x|} = \frac{1}{\cos x}$$

Assuming $x$ is in the range of $\arcsin$, and simultaneously when $\cos x\ne 0$ so $\arcsin y$ is differentiable w.r.t $y$, i.e. $x\in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac\pi2\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\arcsin(x)\;, x= \sin y\;$$

Differentiate

$$ dx= \cos y \; dy $$

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{\cos y}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2y}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}. $$